# Is anyone implementing an interface for Eureqa in R?

Tags: r, interface, machine-learning

Ok this question is not exactly technical but very pertinent and current.

If you may have not heard Eureqa (http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa) is a machine learning (?) based tool that helps you find hidden equations and mathematical relationships within the data. It does sound futuristic and experimental and to a great degree it seems it is.

This is the relevant talk by Eureqa inventor Hod Lipson

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xja6sLl6dVg entitled Mining experimental data.

So i believe this can become popular amongst many R users .

On the official site one can obtain Eureqa clients for MATLAB, Mathematica, Python etc but none so far for R.

So this question is just what it is , is anyone of you working on creating one...or if you know this project do you know what it will take to make one ?

Comment: I see at the Cornell site they've gone to version 2 and renamed it "formulize."  Just to confuse us, I guess :-)

Comment: They are improving and increasing the functions it seems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Eureqa group a few months ago.   Here's the link:

http://groups.google.com/group/eureqa-group/browse_thread/thread/cb251327b50dbd4f

The last entry has the following links:

http://r.eureqa.ivi.eu.com/

http://groups.google.com/group/eureqa-r

I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it works.   If you try it, please post your results.