# R Eurequa interface

Tags: r

http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa/

http://code.google.com/p/eureqa-api/

Is there a way of interfacing Eureqa with R?
(windows os)
Perhaps:

Rcpp package and:

The simplest possible complete C++ program using the Eureqa API:

```
#include eureqa/eureqa.h

#include iostream

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // initialize data set and options
  eureqa::data_set data("my_data.txt");
  eureqa::search_options options("y = f(x)");

  // connect to a eureqa server
  eureqa::connection conn("127.0.0.1");
  conn.send_data_set(data);
  conn.send_options(options);
  conn.start_search();

  // display results
  eureqa::search_progress progress;
  eureqa::solution_frontier solutions;

  while (conn.query_progress(progress))
  {
    solutions.add(progress.solution_);
    std::cout << progress.summary() << std::endl;
    std::cout << solutions.to_string() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you check this question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440430/is-anyone-implementing-an-interface-for-eureqa-in-r which includes a link to this website http://r.eureqa.ivi.eu.com/

Comment: Seems to  be for Linux. Also: This license and the permissions to use this beta version of
the software is valid through June 29, 
2011. At this time, the software usage must be terminated.

Comment: Can you bound the question a little?  That is, do you really want full control of Eureqa from R or just, say, a way to start a run, set a runtime, and dump a few solutions?

Comment: Ideally full control, but otherwise anything that provides a start.

Comment: rgp: R genetic programming framework http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/rgp.pdf looks interesting